# How does one introduce characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, principal-bundles, motivation, de-rham-cohomology

How do you introduce or how are you introduced to characteristic classes.

I am assuming the student is comfortable with principal bundles and connections on principal bundles.

Comment: There is no tag for singular cohomology so could not add it here. Wikipedia article is not doing any good for me.

Comment: I can make it community wiki if necessary,

Comment: I don't know much about the subject, but I really liked the way it is introduced in the book by Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks for your comment. It would be useful if you can write in your own words what characteristic classes mean for you. I am not able to get what characteristic classes are. I request you to make it as an answer. You may take your own time, no problem :)

Comment: Once more I'm definitely not an expert, but if no one write an answer I can try to write a few things for sure.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet thanks. You can even write now, It wold be useful for sure I guess. Thanks.

Comment: cross post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292871/how-does-one-introduce-characteristic-classes

Comment: Bounty is for Thomas Rot. If there is any other good answer I will award bouty for that as well but this bounty is for Thomas Rot. I am not able to award now and have to wait for 23 hours.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet do you want to say something now??

Answer (score 7):

I was always confused by characteristic classes until I understood the definition of characteristic classes via the classifying map.

Corresponding to a vector bundle with structure group $G$ there is a unique homotopy classes of maps $M\rightarrow BG$. In cohomology with coefficients in $A$ this gives a map $H^*(BG;A)\rightarrow H^*(M;A)$. We call the image of any class in $H^*(BG;A)$ a characteristic class.

Now it is true that for certain groups $G$ and coefficients $A$ we know the cohomology ring $BG$ very well. For example for $G=O(n)$ with $A=\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}$ this leads to the Stiefel-Whitney classes or for $G=U(n)$ with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ this leads to the Chern classes.

The relations between these classes directly come from relations between the groups.

EDIT: Let me tell you how to get this map for the tangent bundle of a manifold. Any manifold $M^n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^k$ for $k$ large by Whitney's theorem. But then for every $x\in M$ the tangent space of $M$ at $x$ can be seen as an $n$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Thus we obtain a map $M\rightarrow G_n(\mathbb{R}^k)$ into the Grassmannian of $n$ planes in $\mathbb{R}^k$. With some work you can show that if we have two embeddings, and $k$ is sufficiently large any two embeddings are isotopic and the resulting maps are homotopic. In the end one ends up with a homotopy class of mappings into $G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)=BGL(n)$.

To work this out for general vector bundles you can work as follows: Given a vector bundle $E$ over a reasonable space $M$ find a vector bundle $F$ such that $E\oplus F$ is the trivial bundle over $M$. Then the map that associates to $x\in M$ the subspace $E_x\subset E_x\oplus F_x\cong \mathbb R^k$ defines the classifying map. Again you will have to work a bit to show that this does not depend on the choices if one works up to homotopy.

Comment: I heard about this classifying map many times but did not get enough motivation to actually sit and understand that. +1 for **definition of characteristic classes via the classifying map** I did not understand what does it mean to say **Corresponding to a vector bundle with structure group G there is a unique homotopy classes of maps $M\rightarrow BG$** Given a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ with structure group $G$ what does it mean to say there is a unique homotopy class of maps $M\rightarrow BG$? I know what does it mean to say two maps are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: So, you are saying there are collection of maps $M\rightarrow BG$ all of which are homotopy equivalent to each other.

Comment: Yes. Let me explain how this arises for the tangent bundle.

Comment: Sure Sir.. You can also give some references for this approach :) :)

Comment: Milnor Stasheff

Comment: I do not really know about these classifying spaces and all but I am sure I would understand this once I am comfortable with classifying spaces. It looks reasonable. :) Milnor Stasheff? I saw that book but could not find this approach :O Do you suggest any references for classifying spaces.

Comment: They speak of the grasmannian, which is the same thing. Just start  at the beginning and work slowly. It will be worth it.

Comment: +1 for "Just start at the beginning and work slowly. It will be worth it. " I must admit I was about to ask how does equivalence class of maps $M\rightarrow BG$ induce single map $H^*(BG,A)\rightarrow H^*(M,A)$.. I then remember reading some result which says **deRham cohomology** is invariant under homotopy i.e., two maps which are homotopy equivalent induce same map on deRham cohomology. I was just checking internet that time and saw that this homotopy invariance is also true for singular cohomology also. I did not understand the proof at that time. But, It became useful now :D

Comment: because singular cohomology is homotopy invariant, it induce one single map $H^*(BG,A)\rightarrow H^*(M,A)$ for one homotopy equivalence class of maps $M\rightarrow BG$

Comment: Sir, can you please write down what is $H^*(BG,A)$ here? It does not seem to be deRham cohomology as $BG$ is not a manifold  and $A$ is not $\mathbb{R}$.. Is it the singular cohomology of $BG$ with coefficients from $A$?

Comment: Basically you can take any cohomology theory, for example singular cohomology with any coefficients. De rham is a bit more subtle as you need to approximate everything by finite dim manifolds but i believe this can be done. If I remember correctly Bott and Tu write something about this in the last chapter ( search for the universal bundle)

Comment: Sir, thanks for confirming.. I will see Bott-Tu and also Milnot-Stasheff as you mentioned above... Is there any other place where you can think of which talk about $H^*(BG,A)$.. I would like to understand not just the case of infinite Grassmannian $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ which is classifying space for $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ but for an arbitrary Lie group $G$...